# Proper way to render content with DirectX 2D

Tags: performance, drawing, directx-11

After reading many tutorials on how to draw to device using Direct X, I realize that all these tutorials may have the same mistakes in common. They all draw directly to the device.

For example, I have 20 bitmaps to render to my content + let's say 1000 forms (shapes like rectangle, lines, circle). Every tutorial seems to draw using this approach.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
   RenderTarget.DrawLines(vec2,vec2,Color);
}
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
   RenderTarget.DrawBitmap(bitmap,rectangle);
}
```

This is a basic example written on the spot. But would this approach by kind of slow the more content you need to draw ? Since the RenderTarget is directly link to the device, every call the GPU is going to have to flush state, stop,sync state with the device driver and then draw the new image.

What approach should be used to accomplish this kind of code mentionned above ? I have the same code using GDI+, the difference is that we create a Graphics from a bitmap, then draw to this bitmap using graphics.DrawImage(bitmapX,rect), then finally set that image to the screen.

I believe what I just mentionned is the approach I should follow to render multiple bitmap to the screen using Direct X right ? Is there any tutorials that explain correctly how to do this and not go by drawing every single bitmap directly to the device which is really slow ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firstly, you appear to be using Direct2D, correct? Second, what C# assemblies are you using to access Direct2D APIs?

Comment: I am using SharpDX.Direct2D1 librairies that containes Device, DeviceContext,RenderTarget,Bitmap, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial assumption is wrong; Direct2D1's C/C++ API uses batching and deferred rendering under the hood, so the example provided will actually do things quite efficiently without any additional work by the user.

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371768(v=vs.85).aspx) briefly explains the methods D2D1 uses to implement this batching. Despite your project being written in C#, the C/C++ documentation is the best source for figuring out what's being done - SharpDX merely provides a very thin wrapper around the native layers.

Now, that being said, there are ways to improve the performance of the system. If you know the geometry is not going to change, create a CPU render target and draw everything to a single, all encompassing bitmap and render just that at draw time. Or, if your application architecture supports it, batch up similar sections and render them from multiple threads to a set of different CPU bound rendering targets, and coalesce them later on from the main thread.

Rule of thumb with graphics is to pre-render everything you can, and batch up what you can't (though given your cited knowledge of GDI+, you probably already know this). Here, Direct2D1 has the batching covered, so there's not too much left to do unless profiling reveals a slowdown when using D2D1.

Comment: Thanks, this clarify my thought pretty well ! In my case everything is static, but zooming in and out in the screen makes their position moves to the screen and forces me to redraw with a new screen position right ? Or is their anyway to bypass that? Now my thought was to put everything on a bitmap and takes the right source of it when zooming in and out. But zooming deeply causes blurriness. :(

Comment: If you want to zoom the image, but preserve the resolution, you have no choice but to redraw the image every frame. This is the case no matter what API you use - a resolution preserving zoom manipulates the geometry you're using, not the image, which invalidates anything based on that old geometry. That being said, you can make the process much easier by using `ID2D1RenderTarget::SetTransform` to apply a scaling matrix to the scene, which will allow you to preserve your existing rendering code.

Comment: Writing a windows game myself using just GDI+ at c#, i can state that "create a CPU render target and draw everything to a single, all encompassing bitmap and render just that at draw time" is the best method i found myself too.